# What would be a logical organization of monster taxonomy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, monsters

One of the more idiosyncratic subsystems within 3.x are creature types. [Types were originally devised to make combat more diverse than it was in 2e](https://web.archive.org/web/20161031215141/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20060718a), as types would determine combat statistics similarly to classes. Types would also act as keywords that interact with the magic system: spellcasters, even rangers, [need to know what type their target is and what that means](https://www.runagame.net/2014/06/pathfinder-types-and-select-subtypes.html).

However, this was less than ideal as [determining types was far from intuitive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160911045409/https://monsterdarlings.com/2016/03/02/the-frustration-of-fantasy-taxonomies/), monster statistics had to be eyeballed to ensure they were appropriate for their CR, and [types were pigeonholed into combat roles](https://lonelygm.blogspot.com/2012/03/my-first-prestige-class-and-creatures.html). In Pathfinder Unchained this dual role was largely severed with the introduction of "simple monster creation rules" where combat statistics are determined by the monster's intended role rather than its type.

Glancing over the types, several of them seem [arbitrary or vague](https://sharpenyourgame.wordpress.com/category/creature-feature/). Aberration, dragon, fey, magical beast, [monstrous humanoid](https://knowdirectionpodcast.com/2014/11/he-did-the-monstrous-mash/), and outsider seem [more appropriate as subtypes](http://www.kjd-imc.org/blog/revising-monster-types/) rather than types.

What would be a more logical organization that would avoid redundant or overlapping keywords?

Comment: This question is effectively asking the community to collaboratively create a novel design decision, but since it would be almost entirely based on opinions rather than facts, references, or expertise, that would be inherently off topic for a Stack Exchange. For this kind of community-development-and-design effort, the proper tool is probably an [RPG forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449). It's a fine question; just not one that the SE setup is designed to work for.